# Filter a join based on multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to write a query that filters a join based on several rows in another table. Hard to put it into words, so I'll provide a cut-back simple example.

| Parent | Child |
| --- | --- |
| P1 | C1 |
| P1 | C2 |
| P1 | C3 |
| P2 | C1 |
| P2 | C2 |
| P2 | C4 |
| P3 | C1 |
| P3 | C3 |
| P3 | C5 |

Essentially all rows are stored in the same table, however there is a ParentID allowing one item to link to another (parent) row.

The stored procedure is taking a comma delimited list of "child" codes, and based on whatever is in this list, I need to provide a list of potential siblings.

For example, if the comma delimited list was empty, the returned rows should be C1, C2, C3, C4, C5. If the list is "C2", the returned rows would be C1, C3, C4, and if the list is 'C1, C2', then the only returned row would be c3, c4.

Sample query:

```
SELECT    [S].[ID]
FROM      utItem [P]

    INNER JOIN utItem [C]
        ON [P].[ID] = [C].[ParentID]

    INNER JOIN
    (
    -- Encapsulated to simplify sample.
        SELECT [ID]
        FROM udfListToRows( @ChildList ) 
        GROUP BY
            [ID]
    ) [DT]
    ON [DT].[ID] = [C].[ID]

/* 
In the event where I passed in "C2", this would work, it would return C1, C3, C4.

However this falls apart the moment there is more than 1 value in @ChildList. If I pass in "C2, C3", it would return siblings for either. But I only want siblings of BOTH.
**/
    INNER JOIN [utItem] [S]
        ON [C].[ParentID] = [S].[ParentID]
        AND [C].[ID] <> [S].[ID]

WHERE 
    @ChildList IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    [S].[ID]

UNION ALL
-- In the event that no @ChildList values are provided, return a full list of possible children (e.g. 1,2,3,4,5).
SELECT  [C].[ID]
FROM    [utItem] [P]

INNER JOIN [utItem] [C]
 ON [P].[ID] = [C].[ParentID]

WHERE
    @ChildList IS NULL
GROUP BY
    [C].[ID]
```

Comment: *"if the list is 'C1, C2', then the only returned row would be C3"* Why wouldn't it return `C4` also?

Comment: Sorry yes, correct. I’ll edit that. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can split your data into a table variable for ease of use

```sql
DECLARE @input TABLE (NodeId varchar(2));
INSERT @input (NodeId)
SELECT [ID]
FROM udfListToRows( @ChildList ); -- or STRING_SPLIT or whatever
```

Assuming you already had your data in a proper table variable (rather than a comma-separated list) you can do this

```sql
DECLARE @totalCount int = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @input);

SELECT DISTINCT
  t.Child
FROM (
    SELECT
      t.Parent,
      t.Child,
      i.NodeId,
      COUNT(i.NodeId) OVER (PARTITION BY t.Parent) matches
    FROM YourTable t
    LEFT JOIN @input i ON i.NodeId = t.Child
) t
WHERE t.matches = @totalCount
  AND t.NodeId IS NULL;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9dddf2bebb70475fe87d10e7d9f91273)

This is a kind of relational division

- Left-join the input to the main table
- Using a window function, calculate how many matches you get per `Parent`
- There must be at least as many matches as there are inputs
- We take the distinct `Child`, excluding the original inputs

Comment: Brilliant, thanks, I was not familiar with Window functions, these are incredible. Still trying to understand how your query example is working but it looks to be doing the trick.

Comment: Could we go one step further? What if one parent had two identical children? E.g. C1, C2, C2, C3? I think your code might filter out both C2's. The child code is sort of like a part code so there are instances where there will be duplicates.

Comment: You would need to add a row-number to both sides of the join, and join that also. Something like `FROM (SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Child ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) FROM YourTable t) t LEFT JOIN (SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Child ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) FROM @input i) i ON i.NodeId = t.Child AND i.rn = t.rn`

Comment: Yep, got there in the end. Cheers mate.